# How to use a computer's webcam to read a qr code and open a website [Java]

Tags: java, webcam, qr-code

First let me provide a brief description of what I am trying to accomplish:

I am trying to create a java program that can scan/read a qr code positioned in front of the computer webcam (The QR codes I would be using would all just have url information stored within them). After obtaining the url from the qr code I want to have the program automatically go to the url.

My first question is how do I use a computer webcam with Java.
My second question is how do I decode a QR code once one is captured.

Thank you for your assistance.

Alternatively is it possible to read qr-codes with .net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **Java** you could use [LTI Civil](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lti-civil/) to capture images from a webcam. Then pass the captured images to [ZXing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing) to decode the QR codes.

In **.NET** you could capture the images with [AForge](http://en.code-bude.net/2013/01/02/how-to-easily-record-from-a-webcam-in-c/) and then pass the images to [ZXing.NET](https://github.com/zxing/zxing).

If you need more information, you should ask a more specific question.